# Which mobile game featuring a blue car is this?

Tags: game-identification, mobile

[image: game pic 1]

[image: game pic 2]

These screenshots of a mobile game I have found recently which looks cool. What is the name of this game? And for which platform is this game available, Android or IOS?

Comment: Where did you find the screenshots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Tiny Room Stories: Town Mystery, available on [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1259640/Tiny_Room_Stories_Town_Mystery/), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiarygames.tinyroom), and [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1459520173).